# Show Epic label in backlog without adding Epics to board filter in Jira?

Tags: kanban, jira

There doesn't appear to be any medium here but I have a Kanban board in Jira and all issues are assigned to an Epic. The filter specifically does not include Epics because in Kanban if Epics are included in the filter Jira adds them to the list of work (undesired in my case.) In Agile boards, the Epics do not appear in the backlog.

This is the bahavior I want, however, if I remove epics from the filter, it will not show the Epic tags on the Kanban board. [The Jira documentation mentions the only fix for this is to include Epics in the board filter.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/epic-tag-or-label-is-missing-on-sprint-board-779158640.html) Is there any workaround to this? Is it possible to create another type of Agile board that does not show Epics but also is not running off of sprints? It's highly annoying that this is an all or nothing thing. It doesn't make sense they have functionality for one board but not the other. Perhaps another type of sprint-less board will work?

Answer (score 2):

Moving this to an answer as it got too long for my comment.

There used to be a simplified workflow board that I believe allowed this, but in the new versions I haven't seen it and you can only choose scrum and Kanban.

As a possible workaround, you can modify your filter using labels to fix this issue. What you need to do is add a label to all your tickets that are included in that board, except the Epics. Then modify your board filter to include only tickets that include that label. This will allow you to leave the Epic tags, but not show the Epics themselves.

Obviously this is not ideal since you need to make sure you label everything or it will not show on the board, but it is the only way I know to do what you are asking.